# What are the differences between ps -ef and ps aux in macOS or in Linux?

Tags: macos, ps

When using `ps`, `$ ps -ef` and `$ ps aux` seem to give out the same result. **What are the differences?**

#### What I found

I looked up the manual using `man ps`, and got answers for `-e` and `-f`. But I didn't see `aux` — I used the `/aux` search under `man ps`, but all returned was some legacy notice related to Max OS X Tiger, while I am on macOS High Sierra:

> **LEGACY DESCRIPTION** The biggest change is in the interpretation of the -u option, which now displays processes belonging to the specified username(s).  Thus, "`ps -aux`" will fail (unless you want to know about user "x").  As a convenience, however, "`ps aux`" still works as it did in Tiger.   (March 20, 2005)

So, what are the differences between `ps -ef` and `ps aux`? Thanks!

Comment: When you saw `-ef` you looked up `-e` and `-f` separately. When looking up `aux` you should similarly look up `a`, `u` and `x` separately

Comment: This is not a programming question. Consider deleting it and posting on [unix.se] -- but first check whether it's already been asked there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a small number of command-line tools that have been around a very long time and saw frequent use, enough that for the sake of convenience they started to lose and/or never had formal `-` flags. `tar` and `ps` are two good examples.

Why would you use `aux` versus `ef`? The `f` flag shows process families and groups them together better. `aux` is a long tradition from systems dating back decades, it's expected to work even if it's non-standard.

Historically speaking, macOS is BSD in origin so the arguments for `ps` more closely resemble those of FreeBSD. GNU/Linux inherits from AT&T UNIX (System V) which had similar tools which evolved in different ways. There's a lot of overlap between these two worlds, many tools jumped from one to the other, but there's still some historical reasons why some arguments are different.

Keep in mind `ps` isn't "`bash` stuff", it's a system command that you can use with `bash`, as well as other shells, or no shell at all when called directly. Try not to confuse the command-line environment offered by shells like `bash` with the suite of POSIX/UNIX tools like `ps` that are bundled as part of your operating system.

Comment: I didn't know that `aux` is preferred than `-ef` for better performance. I just saw people using them like interchangeably. You mentioned the command-line environment like `bash` and the OS tools like `ps`. I am now kinda puzzled about their connections...

Comment: I guess it is just as you said, that `aux` is expected to work without special notice. And thus the manual page did not include it.

Comment: @jackxujh I've used `ps aux` since forever and I think a lot of other people expect it to work regardless of the system's lineage or history. While `netstat` and `route` have wildly different, often incompatible options, `ps` has made some concessions to cross-platform compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Some options are identical, some close.  Basically `aux` is BSD style and `-ef` is UNIX style.  From the first part of the Linux man page (I assume the OSX version has similar reasoning for supporting both types):

```
   This version of ps accepts several kinds of options:

   1   UNIX options, which may be grouped and must be preceded by a dash.
   2   BSD options, which may be grouped and must not be used with a dash.
   3   GNU long options, which are preceded by two dashes.
```

The detailed info on `-ef` and `aux` is in the man page.  I'm just trying to clarify confusion you might be having on why they are both supported.

The linux man page also details some consistent differences when BSD options are used.  This may or not be true for MacOS, so I won't link it.

Comment: I noticed the end of the `man ps` page has **BSD**, but has not introduction of the `aux` argument.

Comment: aux is not a single argument, but 3. `a` `u` `x` Check out the ubuntu man page:  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/ps.1.html

Comment: Oh now I get it! `a`ll user, `u`ser-oriented format, and `x` restriction-lifting.

Comment: I just checked the Mac `man ps` page again. It listed UNIX options, despite the page title as *BSD General Commands Manual*.